# How to cover a set of circles in a plane with disjoint circles of constant radius?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, language-agnostic, mathematical-optimization, computational-geometry

So you have a sheet / area of a given dimension, and within this area are holes (their center point(x,y) and radius are given). The problem is you need to cover these holes with patches. These circular patches have a fixed radius (ie: radius of 5) and are not allowed to overlap with each other (but can touch). You're allowed to use as many as you like, the goal is not to find the most optimal number, but to see if it's possible to cover every single hole.

I've solved a similar problem with a KD tree, but due to the 3D dimensional nature of the holes in this problem, I'm unsure on how to approach it. Just looking for a pointer in the right direction, not the coded solution :)

Comment: This is a very interesting problem indeed!  But please be aware that your question as it is stated currently is not a proper question for StackOverflow.  "Pointers in the right direction" just isn't what SO is about.  Here you can state a clearly defined problem which must be of a nature so that it probably will have a clear and correct answer.  Your question belongs in the realm of "primarily opinion based" or similar.  So don't be too surprised if it gets closed.  Good luck anyway :-)

Comment: Very interesting question indeed, it might receive more attention on the [computer science stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). But what do you mean by 3D nature of the holes ?

Comment: @m.raynal The previous time I used a KD tree, I was dealing with points (x,y). But with this problem i'll have both x,y and the radius because my data set are circles (of various sizes) not points. Not sure if it makes it "3D", but it seems harder to sort into a space partioning tree than your standard x,y points :)

Comment: I am not even sure how this problem is tractable with points instead of circles. Furthermore I cannot see how a KD tree helps for this problem. I guess it would help if you could briefly explain how that original solution worked.

Comment: Have you [cross-posted this on CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/109124/1960)  with a different account?

Comment: IMO opinion, you need to find the geometric solution before caring about efficiency and acceleration data structures such as a kD-tree. I also believe that this is a terrible problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the sizes of the patches and the holes there may be no solution.

Solution with most compact patches array:

[image]

No solution because hole is bigger than patches, which allows uncovered areas:

[image]

No solution because holes are too close:

[image]

For a general construction you begin with a patch centered on the hole. Then translate and rotate (around the center of a contiguous patch) the patch as required:

[image]

Comment: Cheers. Would this also work for covering multiple holes with a single patch? Let’s say each hole had a varying radius of 1-3 and the patches had a radius of 5?

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for an analytical or at least a deterministic solution for this. But I'm afraid it's too complicated to have one. [Metaheuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic) like [EA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm)s, on the other hand, can cope with this kind of problems due to their stochastic nature. You have to change your problem to an [optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem) when you decide to adopt such approach.

I tried to solve this using the basic form [DE algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution). To define an optimization problem I assumed that a solution vector is a an array of `2*N` floating point variables, where `N` is the number of holes. This array represents `X` and `Y` coordinates of patches, since `N` patches are needed at most to cover `N` holes.

The cost function (that is needed to get minimized) is defined as follows:

```
Find closest patch to each hole
Find A1 as sum of uncovered areas of holes by their closest patchs
Find A2 as sum of intersection areas of active(!) patches
return max(A1, A2)
```

In this function an active patch is a patch that is the closest one to at least one hole. This definition is added to the problem to cover the situation you mentioned in your comment to Ripi2's answer (when a patch covers two holes, so there's another patch that is useless). To be more descriptive, let's assume that there's this `P1` patch that is not the closest one to any of holes. `H1` is closest hole to this patch, but its closest patch is `P2`. So we can say for sure that intersection area of `H1` and `P1` is less than or equal to the one of `H1` and `P2`. Since this is true about its closest hole, it will be the same for all other holes, so let's think that it doesn't exist!

This is a sample:

[image]

Just keep in mind that these algorithms never guarantee to find the global optimum, however, they will give a [set of] sub-optimal solution[s] at hand.